# Al ingresar datos a la base de datos, solo me envía 0

Tags: php

Buen día, solicito su ayuda, estoy tratando de envía una cadena de datos a la base de datos, básicamente son varias variables que forman una oración

```
$codigoanterior = $_POST["nuevoIdAbono"];
        $fechaObservaciones = 'Un nuevo abono fue generado el dia ';
        $fechaObservaciones1 = $fechaObservaciones .$fecha;
        $ahora = 'y ahora resta ';
        $ahora1 = $ahora .$restanteAbono; 
        $listo = $fechaObservaciones1 .$ahora1;
        $observaciones= $listo;
        var_dump($listo);
        $datosActualizar = $Observaciones;
                        

            $respuestaActualizar = ModeloVentas::mdlEditarVenta2($tabla, $datosActualizar, $codigoanterior);
            var_dump($respuestaActualizar);
```

/*=============================================
Esto recibe editar ventas 2
=============================================*/

```
static public function mdlEditarVenta2($tabla, $datos, $codigo){

    $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("UPDATE $tabla SET  observaciones = :observaciones WHERE codigo = :codigo");

    $stmt->bindParam(":codigo", $codigo, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(":observaciones", $datos, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    

    if($stmt->execute()){

        return "ok";

    }else{

        return "error";
    
    }

    $stmt->close();
    $stmt = null;

}
```

El modelo recibe los datos y hace un Update a mi columna observaciones, y me retorna ok, pero lo que ingresa es un 0, si envío por ejemplo números al azar, si me los ingresa bien, pero no soy capaz de enviar esta cadena, la columna donde hace el update es de tipo Text, y pues ya no se que hacer, ya probé enviarlo de diferentes maneras, y solo me ingresa el 0 si envío letras, pero si envío números, me los ingresa bien, espero alguien pueda ayudarme, gracias

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! uqe hace mdlEditarVenta2?

Comment: ya entonces tenemos que adivinar el contenido de `mdlEditarVenta2`

Comment: listo actualizado

Comment: Pues, si quieres enviar un texto pero le dices `PARAM_INT` al añadir los parámetros, algo va a salir mal :)

Comment: @Alfabravo infinitas gracias, era eso, definitivamente un error tonto, y es que soy muy nuevo en esto, definitivamente me faltan mas bases

Comment: @Xtrofiahw nah, todos estamos en el mismo proceso. Me alegra que lo resolvieras :)